# Is this the correct way to host multiple Tomcat 7 applications using the same data sources?

Tags: tomcat7, jndi, multi-tenant

OK, normally we have been installing a Tomcat 7 instance for each web app because, while they are almost the same code base (same app really), we can't afford having one app down for changes and it affect other customers.

But installing so many Tomcats is getting old.  So we thought we would reduce the number of Tomcats to one per customer group.

Anyway, our Hibernate configs use JNDI and I thought I would create a universal context.xml file per Tomcat group and store that in the `CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` so that all applications under the same group could share the same production db data sources.

I would do the same thing on my local Tomcat for development and just have the context there contain development data source information.  So that I can just deploy a war to the production server or my local development server and not have to change context files around.

I am assuming that if I keep the following scheme, I should be able to pull this off.

```
CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml  # either contains production or dev connections
CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/    # EMPTY - don't want apps overwriting data sources
CATALINA_BASE/webapps/<webapp>/META-INF/context.xml  # almost BLANK.
```

This seems to work so far (only tested with one web app) but it looks like the context.xml in `<webapp>/META-INF` has to contain a valid context and a context path.  Why is that?  Does that path have to be different for each web app?  Currently, there is no connection information in that file (it's only in the `conf/context.xml`).

Bottom line, I want each web app to be "dumb" in where it gets the database connection information so that I can just drop war files anywhere and they are automatically wired up.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your DataSource definition in $CATALINA_BASE/context.xml the same *definition* gets used for each web application so you will have multiple DataSources.

If you want one DataSource shared between multiple applications, add the DataSource definition as a global resource in server.xml and add a ResourceLink to $CATALINA_BASE/context.xml

META-INF/context.xml is not a required file. You can leave it out completely. If it is present it must be a valid context.xml file ( is valid for example) but - as per the docs - it must not contain any path or docBase information.